# crosstab function behaves differently inside loop than outside

Tags: r, loops

I am trying to use a loop to run crosstabs. The crosstab function (from the pollster package) behaves differently in the loop than outside of it. I will use the illinois dataset in the pollster package for my example here.

If I run it outside the loop

```
library(pollster)

xtab2 <- illinois |> 
  crosstab(educ6, maritalstatus, weight = weight)

xtab2
```

I get a table

| educ6 | Married | Widow/divorced | Never married | n |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| LT | 40.01702 | 29.05581 | 30.92717 | 10770999 |
| HS | 52.87883 | 20.98206 | 26.13911 | 31409418 |
| Some Col | 44.56356 | 17.42161 | 38.01483 | 21745113 |
| AA | 57.40460 | 18.37234 | 24.22307 | 8249909 |
| BA | 61.14996 | 11.29282 | 27.55722 | 19937965 |
| Post-BA | 70.65086 | 12.86814 | 16.48100 | 10565110 |

But if I run:

```
loop_vars <- c("maritalstatus")

for(i in loop_vars){ 
  
xtab2 <- illinois |>
  crosstab(educ6, i, weight = weight)
}

xtab2
```

The the table looks like:

| educ6 | maritalstatus | n |
| --- | --- | --- |
| LT | 100 | 10770999 |
| HS | 100 | 31409418 |
| Some Col | 100 | 21745113 |
| AA | 100 | 8249909 |
| BA | 100 | 19937965 |
| Post-BA | 100 | 19937965 |

Why is R reading the exact same code differently when it's in a loop?

Comment: The difference isn't the loop, it's using a unquoted variable name vs a string, `illinois |> crosstab(educ6, maritalstatus, weight = weight)` vs `illinois |> crosstab(educ6, "maritalstatus", weight = weight)`. In the first, `maritalstatus` is correctly interpreted as a column name. In the second, `"maritalstatus"` is introduced as a new value. I've never used `pollster` before, but it looks like it's built on `dplyr` so you could try a solution [as in this `dplyr` FAQ]`, something like `.data[[i]]` or perhaps `{{i}}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone runs across a similar problem, doing this solved it

```
loop_vars <- c("maritalstatus")

for(i in loop_vars){ 
  
  var <- i
  
xtab2 <- illinois |>
  crosstab(educ6, !!ensym(var), weight = weight)
}

xtab2
```